# odoo v8 user cannot create company?

Tags: odoo-8

I created a group at setting->Users->Groups. and did the access right->Companies and gave the full permission.

And I created a user (test1), and I put the user into the created group. I gave the Administration->settings.

And I login as test1 user, tried to create new company.

but I got the following error.

> The requested operation cannot be completed due to security
>   restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.
>
> (Document type: res.company, Operation: read)

How can do to create new company by new user?

Comment: Are you planning to setup odoo for multi company?

Comment: yes, I'm doing to setup odoo for multi company

Answer (score 0):

**to mark "Multi Companies" at settings->Users->Users->new user**